# Passing different values for Shared Preferences

Tags: android, json, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-volley

I'm an inexperienced Android learner here!

So I'm learning, and on my project, I have to use the url and `shared preferences (Volley)` to show the items in `Recycler View`.

So the **categories** take `user_id` and `api_key` as parameters, and after that the **subcategories** take `user_id`, `cat_id`, and `api_key` as parameters.

I used JSONObject to parse the categories, and I tried to save the **category ids** in `shared preferences`.

So after that in the `SubcategoryFragment`, I called the `shared preferences` again, and it ran. But I noticed that for all the category items, only one id was used for the subcategories. So basically multiple categories are calling the same subcategory.

I think it because in my `SubcategoryFragment` code, I called the shared preferences' editor only once, while in the CategoryFragment, I put the editor in the for loop for JSON Array.

Please let me know what you think. I appreaciate it!

My CategoryFragment that saved the `categoryID`:

```
    var catList = ArrayList<CategoryItem>()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_act, container, false)

        //Recycler view
        view.recyclerViewCat.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        var sp: SharedPreferences = this.activity!!.getSharedPreferences("chamber", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var editor = sp.edit()


        var iD = sp.getString("user_id", "Default")
        var apiKey = sp.getString("user_apikey", "Default")

        val url = "XXXX.php?cust_category.php?api_key=$apiKey&user_id=$iD"

        var stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,

            Response.Listener {

                var jsonObject = JSONObject(it)

                var jsonArrayCats =jsonObject.getJSONArray("category")

                for(i in 0 until jsonArrayCats.length()){

                    var cats =jsonArrayCats.getJSONObject(i)

                    var cID = cats.getString("cid")
                    var cName = cats.getString("cname")
                    var cDes = cats.getString("cdiscription")
                    var cImg = cats.getString("cimagerl")

                    catList.add(CategoryItem(cID, cName, cDes, cImg))

                    editor.putString("cat_id", cID)
                    editor.putString("cat_name", cName)
                    editor.putString("cat_des", cDes)
                    editor.putString("cat_Img", cImg)

                }
                editor.apply()

                val adapter = CatAdapter(catList, view.context)
                view.recyclerViewCat.adapter = adapter

            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                Toast.makeText(view.context, "invalid api key or user id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        )

        Volley.newRequestQueue(view.context).add(stringRequest)

        return view
    }
```

And my `SubcategoryFragment` that uses it:

```
    var scatList = ArrayList<SubCategoryItem>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_category, container, false)

        view.recyclerViewSubCat.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        var sp: SharedPreferences = this.activity!!.getSharedPreferences("chamber", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var editor = sp.edit()

        var catId = sp.getString("cat_id", "Default")
        var apiKey = sp.getString("user_apikey", "Default")
        var userId = sp.getString("user_id", "Default")

        val url = "XXXXX.php?Id=$catId&api_key=$apiKey&user_id=$userId"

        var stringReq = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener {

                var jsonObject = JSONObject(it)
                var jsonArraySCat = jsonObject.getJSONArray("subcategory")

                for(i in 0 until jsonArraySCat.length()){

                    var scats = jsonArraySCat.getJSONObject(i)

                    var scID = scats.getString("scid")
                    var scName = scats.getString("scname")
                    var scDes = scats.getString("scdiscription")
                    var scImg = scats.getString("scimageurl")

                    editor.putString("scat_id", scID)
                    editor.putString("scat_name", scName)
                    editor.putString("scat_des", scDes)
                    editor.putString("scat_Img", scImg)

                    scatList.add(SubCategoryItem(scID, scName, scDes, scImg))

                }

                editor.commit()

                val adapter = SubCatAdapter(scatList, view.context)
                view.recyclerViewSubCat.adapter = adapter

            },

            Response.ErrorListener {
                Log.e("ERROR", it.message.toString())
                Toast.makeText(view.context, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        )

        Volley.newRequestQueue(view.context).add(stringReq)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `SharedPreferences`  overrides the value which have the same key.
For example there will be only one value for key "scid" in your "chamber" `SharedPreferences` -

So if you do something like this -

```
for(i in 0 until jsonArraySCat.length()){
    editor.putString("scat_id", scID)
}
```

than value for key "scat_id" will be overridden each time it is being called.

Sol. - 
You can save the complete `JSONObject` as a `String` in your `SharedPreferences` like -

```
editor.putString("jsonResponse", jsonObject.toString())
```

And than parse and reuse it.

**UPDATE:**

Update your code like this -

```
Response.Listener {
  var stringReq = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,

//Save in SharedPref
    editor.putString("api_response", it)
    editor.commit()

//Use a common parsing function
scatList = getParsedData(it)          //it or from SharedPref

val adapter = SubCatAdapter(scatList, view.context)
view.recyclerViewSubCat.adapter = adapter

}
```

// A common function to parse your data

```
fun getParsedData(strResponse: String?): List<SubCategoryItem>{
  if(!strResponse.isNullOrEmpty()){
    try{
      val list = ArrayList<SubCategoryItem>()
      var jsonObject = JSONObject(it)
      var jsonArraySCat = jsonObject.getJSONArray("subcategory")

repeat(jsonArraySCat.length()){                    //use repeat than for loop
  jsonArraySCat.getJSONObject(it).run{
    SubCategoryItem(getString("scid"), scats.getString("scname"), scats.getString("scdiscription"), scats.getString("scimageurl")).also{
      list.add(it)
    }
  }
}
return list    //return parsed data list
}catch(e: JSONException){
  Log.d(TAG, "Parse Exception $e")  
}
}
return ArrayList()  //return empty list
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So basically by doing this, I will have the json as a String, call it in the other fragment, and parse the json again?

Comment: Thank you! So I did that, call the shared preference in the next fragment, and used a for loop to parse the json array. Then I also put the url and the whole string request inside that for loop, and I got error `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`, `Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` and `Caused by: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of`

Comment: You'r getting this exception because the string you are trying to convert into json is empty. Also always use try/catch with JSONException when parsing json data.

Comment: Answer Updated @HumbleHermit

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I never knew there was a 'repeat' thing